# Multiple find in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, match

I have collection `items` in MongoDB with following documents:

```json
{ name: "A", value: 1 },
{ name: "B", value: 2 },
{ name: "C", value: 3 }
```

Now, I have several filters, that I want to apply to search first document, that matches filter. Is there any way to do it in one query, or I just need repeat `db.items.findOne()`?

My filters are:

```json
{ name: "B" }, // Matches second document.
{ value: 3 }, // Matches third document.
{ $or: [{name: "B"}, {"name": "C"}] } // Matches second document.
```

The result should be (including duplicate document and correct order):

```json
{ name: "B", value: 2 },
{ name: "C", value: 3 },
{ name: "B", value: 2 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $facet aggregation.

With this operator you could run multiple queries at once like this: [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vfk-y6aTpJt)

Once you got your desired result you could map the documents as you want with $project and $replaceRoot. [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1ch_fAYN-KN)